# Angular 2 materialize css

Tags: angular, materialize, angular2-material

I use Angular 2 with Webpack module bundler, i followed this tutorial to add Materialize css into my project. Then i get stuck at this error message:
[Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is created by the materialize-css library. Please import materialize-css before importing angular2-materialize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziD0o.jpg)

Does anyone experience this before?
Any help  will be much welcomed.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? If you show code examples of how you imported the modules I may be able to help. Point me in the direction of the instructions you followed also.

Comment: i didn't know how to fix this bug. Then i reversed my code and  added jquery, materialize.min.js into script property of angular-cli.json. Surprisingly,  it worked.

Comment: How did you add jquerry ? can you provide an answer to your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

To integrate Materialize CSS with Angular 6:

1. Install all dependencies:

   `npm install jquery hammerjs materialize-css@next angular2-materialize --save`
2. Add the js files for these dependencies inside the apps section and then inside scripts subsection in file `angular.json`:

   ```
   "styles": [  
   "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
     "src/styles.scss"
   ],
   "scripts": [
     "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
     "./node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
     "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
   ]
   ```
3. Import materialize-css and MaterializeModule in the main `app.module`:

   ```
   ...
   import 'materialize-css';
   import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';
   ...
   @NgModule({
   imports: [
   ...
   MaterializeModule,
   ],
   })
   ```
4. Restart your server

sources:

https://fullstackengine.net/create-wedding-page-angular-materialize/

http://colinstodd.com/blog/post/how-to-install-materialize-css-in-angular-5

[Angular 5 with materialize css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498408/angular-5-with-materialize-css)