# Angular 5 with materialize css

Tags: angular5, materialize, angular-module

I'm learning angular 5. but I was following this tutorial to import materialize css module to my app. [Ang with angular2materialize](http://fullstackengine.net/create-wedding-page-angular-materialize/)
then I run ng serve and it compiled successfully. but when I load the content it return an error

> Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is created by the materialize-css library. Please import materialize-css before importing angular2-materialize.

how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import 'materialize-css';` **before** `import {MaterializeModule} from 'angular2-materialize';` in app.module.ts.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

You can use materialize css in 2 ways either by downloading or using CDNs. Add these lines in you app.component.html. These are the links to CDNs. Other versions of CDNs https://cdnjs.com/libraries/materialize